# SSRS exact month difference

Tags: date, reporting-services

This may have been asked before but I've not been able to find it having searched! In Oracle SQL there's a function called MONTHS_BETWEEN which returns a fractional value if the two dates you are comparing are not both the first day of the month for example. I need to do something similar in SSRS report builder, I've tried using DateDiff("m",Date1,Date2) however this always returns an integer and I think from what I can tell it just compares the two months from the dates, so when I compare 30/09/20 and 01/04/21 I get 7 months when actually it is much closer to 6.

Is there a function or a fix that can be used in SSRS to get that more accurate value?

Thank you!

For example I would like to get the following result:

Difference between 30/09/20 and 01/04/21 = 6.1

Difference between 01/08/20 and 30/09/20 = 1.9

It doesn't have to super accurate as I will be rounding to the nearest integer but I'm looking for something that will recognise that in the second example nearly 2 months have been covered and in the first example it's only just over 6 months.

Comment: The DateDiff function returns the number of 'boundaries' crossed so that's why you are getting 7 returned. It would help if you showed a few examples of dates and the expected returned value, especially for those of us that do not use Oracle. Please edit your question and add a couple of exmaples then I'm sure we'll get an answer.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I have added in examples, I hope that makes it clearer!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need an approximation then you could just calculate the number of days difference and divide by 30.

using the following expression...

```
=DATEDIFF("d", Fields!startDate.Value, Fields!endDate.Value)/30
```

I put a few more examples into a table and got the following results.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following code mimics oracle definition of months_between

```
Public Function MonthsBetween( d1 As Date, d2 As Date) As Decimal

Dim df As Decimal

df = DateDiff("m", d1, d2)

If  Day(d1) <> Date.DaysInMonth(Year(d1), Month(d1)) Or Day(d2) <> Date.DaysInMonth(Year(d2), Month(d2)) Then

df = df + Cdec((Day(d2)-Day(d1))/31)

End If


Return df

End Function
```

- Integer result when both dates are last day of month
- Negative result when date1 > date2
- Decimal part based on 31 days month

  For your expression use something like

`=Code.MonthsBetween(Fields!date1.Value , Fields!date2.Value)`

[image]

**UPDATE**

The following expression works in the same manner

```
= Cdec(
DateDiff("m", Fields!date1.Value, Fields!date2.Value)
+
Iif  (
 Day(Fields!date1.Value) <> Date.DaysInMonth(Year(Fields!date1.Value), Month(Fields!date1.Value)) Or 
Day(Fields!date2.Value) <> Date.DaysInMonth(Year(Fields!date2.Value), Month(Fields!date2.Value)) ,
 Cdec( (Day(Fields!date2.Value) - Day(Fields!date1.Value))/31),
0.0
)
)
```